# Migration of multi-value pictures to user fields

Tags: 7, migrations

I need to migrate from a WordPress site to a Drupal 7 site where users could upload their own images (like multiple user pictures). I have a CSV file with the User's ID and a serialized array containing the filenames of uploaded pictures (no, really).

Users have a multi-value image field 'field_user_pictures'.

After deserializing the array, drupal complains with the error "ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". (Presumably because MigrateDestinationFile doesn't handle arrays very well.) Then I tried with just using the first image of the array, and that actually works. What doesn't work, however, is to get drupal to link this sole image to the 'field_user_pictures' user field.

I have been trying to get to something like this:

```
 class PictureMigration extends Migration
 {
    public function __construct ($arguments)
        {
        parent::__construct($arguments);

        $source = 'user_pictures.csv';

        $columns = array(
            1 => array('source_userid', ''),
            3 => array('source_serialized', ''),
        );

        $source_key = array('source_userid' => array('type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE),);

        $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($source, $columns);
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('image', 'MigrateFileUri');
        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, $source_key, MigrateDestinationFile::getKeySchema());

        $this->addFieldMapping('source_dir')->defaultValue($this->remote_dir);
        $this->addFieldMapping('destination_dir')->defaultValue('public://');
        $this->addFieldMapping('value', 'source_serialized');
      }

  public function prepareRow($row) {
     // snipped
     $row->source_serialized = $this->deserializePhotos($row->source_serialized); // returns array of filenames
    }   
}

public class UserMigration extends Migration {
  public class __construct ($arguments) {
    // snipped...
      $this->addFieldMapping('field_user_pictures')->sourceMigration('PictureMigration');
  }
}
```

The first problem is that MigrateDestinationFile doesn't seem to like multi-value values; the second problem is that even when I only use the first filename of the array, it still doesn't get linked to the 'field_user_pictures' field...

See also: [Migration: Combine Profile2 and file migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138673/migration-combine-profile2-and-file-migration) -- almost exactly the same issue, but with no valid answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something is really odd about your code `$this->destination` is a `MigrateDestinationFile` yet `$this->map` is trying to track a `MigrateDestinationNode` .... I've never done anything that way.

I would do the following:

1. Import Users from Wordpress to Drupal.
2. Use your CSV file of legacy UIDs and picture files to run an `update` of the (newly) created Drupal users and insert the images as needed.

I'm doing this now as we speak on a `Document` content type of which there are 120k entries, but only 4k have movie files associated with them so I feel a node revision is a better use the time to import stuff.

This is an example from some work in progress and will not run as-is but it should be a concrete example:

```
class PrezDocumentMediaMigration extends PrezMigration {

  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $document_fields = array(
      // ... fields ...
    );
    $this->description = 'Update created Documents with audio and video from legacy DB. There are only ~5k of entries.';

    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy_migration')
      ->select('papers', 'p')
      ->fields('p', $document_fields)
      ->condition('av', 0, '<>');
    // Additional pseudo fields to move data from legacy derived data to drupal.
    $query->addExpression('NULL', 'local_video');
    $query->addExpression('NULL', 'remote_video');
    $query->addExpression('NULL', 'local_audio');
    $query->addExpression('NULL', 'remote_audio');

    $options = array('track_changes' => 1);

    $count_query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy_migration')
      ->select('papers', 'p')
      ->condition('av', 0, '<>');
    $count_query->addExpression('COUNT(pid)', 'cnt');

    // We are updating existing content in Drupal.
    $this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $document_fields, $count_query, $options);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('documents');
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
                                   array(
                                     'pid' => array(
                                       'type'     => 'int',
                                       'unsigned' => FALSE,
                                       'not null' => TRUE,
                                       'description' => 'Unique content reference legacy document',
                                       'alias' => 'doc',
                                     )
                                   ),
                                   MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );

    // Migration mappings, the documentation for these mappings can be seen at:
    // https://www.drupal.org/node/1133448

    $migrator_user = user_load_by_name('PrezMigrator');

    // Some default values for sanity.
    $this->addFieldMapping('uid')
      ->defaultValue($migrator_user->uid);
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision')
      ->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('log')
      ->defaultValue('inserted related media from legacy DB on ' . date("l jS of F g:i A.", time()));
    $this->addFieldMapping('promote')->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('sticky')->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('revision_uid')->defaultValue($migrator_user->uid);

    // What legacy content are we talking about ?
    // also we want this legacy ID to actually lookup through 2 source migrations.
    $this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'id')->sourceMigration(array('PrezDietNonPresidents','PrezDietPresidents'));

    // Map media files these are multiple value fields. They can accept a PHP array of values.
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local', 'local_video');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_remote', 'remote_video');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_audo_local', 'local_audio');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_audio_remote', 'remote_audio');

    // Each of the above media fields will need the following additional subfields
    // Only 1 is provided as an example to keep this example shorter:
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:file_class')
      ->defaultValue('MigrateFileUri');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:language')
      ->defaultValue(LANGUAGE_NONE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:preserve_files')
      ->defaultValue(FALSE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:file_replace')
      ->defaultValue(FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:source_dir')
      ->defaultValue('/var/www/2015/presidency/drupal7-project/build/legacy/htdocs/www/media/');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:urlencode')
      ->defaultValue(FALSE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:alt')->defaultValue('');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_docs_media_videos_local:title')
      ->defaultValue('');


    // List fields not be migrated to destination.
    $this->addUnmigratedDestinations(
      array(
        // ... massive list of fields.
      ));

  }

  public function prepareRow($row) {
    // Always include this fragment at the beginning of every prepareRow()
    // implementation, so parent classes can ignore rows.
    if (parent::prepareRow($row) === FALSE) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $youtube_format = 3;
    $quicktime_format = 2;
    $audio_format = 1;

    switch ($row->av) {
      case $youtube_format:
        $row->remote_video = $this-> find_remote_video($row->medialink);
        break;
      case $quicktime_format:
        $row->local_video = $this->find_local_video($row->medialink);      
        break;
      case $audio_format:
        $row->local_audio = $this->find_local_audio($row->av, $row->medialink);        
      default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex
  protected function find_remote_video($link) {
      $separator = '***';
    $text = preg_replace('~
        # Match non-linked youtube URL in the wild. (Rev:20130823)
        https?://         # Required scheme. Either http or https.
        (?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)? # Optional subdomain.
        (?:               # Group host alternatives.
          youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube         # or youtube.com or
          (?:-nocookie)?  # youtube-nocookie.com
          \.com           # followed by
          \S*             # Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
          [^\w\s-]       # but char before ID is non-ID char.
        )                 # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{11})      # $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
        (?=[^\w-]|$)     # Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
        (?!               # Assert URL is not pre-linked.
          [?=&+%\w.-]*    # Allow URL (query) remainder.
          (?:             # Group pre-linked alternatives.
            [\'"][^<>]*>  # Either inside a start tag,
          | </a>          # or inside <a> element text contents.
          )               # End recognized pre-linked alts.
        )                 # End negative lookahead assertion.
        [?=&+%\w.-]*        # Consume any URL (query) remainder.
        ~ix',
                         '//www.youtube.com/embed/$1' . $separator,
                         $link);
    return explode($separator, $text);
  }

  // other "find" media methods that return filesystem paths and stuff depending on where the media
  // existed in the legacy system.
}
```

Comment: But how do I actually insert the images in the user's profile?